# Difference between onLoad and ng-init in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular. I don't understand what is difference between onLoad and ng-init for initialization of a variable. In which scope it creates this variable.

`For example`

```
<ng-include onLoad="selectedReq=reqSelected" src="'partials/abc.html'"></ng-include>
```

`OR`

```
<ng-include ng-init="selectedReq=reqSelected" src="partials/abc.html"></ng-include>
```

Please also give me some idea about isolated scope.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`ng-init` is a directive that can be placed inside `div`'s, `span`'s, whatever, whereas `onload` is an attribute specific to the `ng-include` directive that functions as an `ng-init`.  To see what I mean try something like:

```
<span onload="a = 1">{{ a }}</span>
<span ng-init="b = 2">{{ b }}</span>
```

You'll see that only the second one shows up.

An isolated scope is a scope which does not prototypically inherit from its parent scope.  In laymen's terms if you have a widget that doesn't need to read and write to the parent scope arbitrarily then you use an isolate scope on the widget so that the widget and widget container can freely use their scopes without overriding each other's properties.

Answer (score 26):

From angular's documentation,

**ng-init** SHOULD NOT be used for any initialization. It should be used only for aliasing.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

**onload** should be used if any expression needs to be evaluated after a partial view is loaded (by ng-include).
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

The major difference between them is when used with **ng-include**.

```
<div ng-include="partialViewUrl" onload="myFunction()"></div>
```

In this case, **myFunction** is called everytime the partial view is loaded.

```
<div ng-include="partialViewUrl" ng-init="myFunction()"></div>
```

Whereas, in this case, **myFunction** is called only once when the parent view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
<div ng-show="$scope.showme === true">Hello World</div>
<div ng-repeat="a in $scope.bigdata" ng-init="$scope.showme = true">{{ a.title }}</div>
```