# What is the order in which various load functions/methods execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cross-browser

`$(document).ready()`, `$(window).load(function()`, `<body onload="load()">`, `data-ng-init="init()"`, `$(function(){...});`

There are probably about ten other "load" functions between jQuery, Angular, and old-fashioned JavaScript; I cannot find a definitive resource which states in which order these various methods actually fire (across diverse browsers might be another consideration). How many more are there? What are they called? In what order do they do their magic?

Comment: The duplicate covers most of them, but there's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395780/difference-between-onload-and-ready and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441775/difference-between-onload-and-ng-init-in-angular

Comment: @Anonymous because these are separate questions, it isn't what I'm looking for. I'd like it all spelled out in one place. jQuery, Angular and vanilla JS.

Comment: True, it is not all one resource, but you can get a pretty good idea of what each one does and the relative time that they finish from looking at them.

Comment: @Anonymous A "pretty good idea" is not what I want. Please don't close.

Comment: Still, typing any combination of two functions that you mentioned into a search engine will show a specific Stack Overflow question about the difference between those two.  Then, when looked at in its entirety, the order becomes evident.

Comment: There are only two events you usually listen to: DOM is completely loaded and manipulable, and all static resources (such as images) are loaded. DOM ready fires before resources ready. There might be other events that the frameworks itself are triggering when they reach a certain state, but those don't have anything to do with the browser. And if that's whats your question is about, you should probably ask specifically for that framework.

Comment: @FelixKling No, the question of the browser was an afterthought. I really don't care about anything but modern browsers, but thought that I'd include it parenthetically in the questions in case there was anything browser-related connected to this issue that is particularly repugnant.

Comment: With "browser" I meant events triggered by the browser to notify scripts about the page loading state. Poor word choice on my end.

Answer (score 2):

Why Don't you Check it yourself?

---

## `Fiddle`

---

As you can see as soon as your `DOM` becomes ready `$(document).ready()` is fired and so `$(function(){...});`. As `$(function(){...});` is another way of representing `$(document).ready()`, It'll not wait for all `images` and `iframes` to `load`.

Also `$(window).load(function()`, `<body OnLoad='function()'>` & `window.onload = function(){}` are same and these event fires when all the content on your page fully loaded including the `DOM`content frames and images. So its kinda slower.

---

You can Use inline `OnLoad` for many other elements like `img`, `link`, `scripts` etc.

Like:

```
<img src="myImage.gif" onload="OnLoadImage()" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css" onload="StyleSheetLoaded();" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" Onload="ScriptLoaded();"></script>
```

---

`onload` is supported by the following HTML tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <link>, <script>
```

And the following Javascript objects:

```
image, layer, window
```

---

Also JavaScript is Browser Dependant and not library Dependant So it'll be constant for all browsers.

Sorry I don't know about the **`data-ng-init="init()"`**, Which library of JavaScript is it?

Hope it'll Help you. Cheers :)!

Comment: That fiddle link is awesomely big, +1. The reason I cannot fiddle it is because I believe there are many more "load" methods than I am aware of.

Comment: `data-ng-init="init()"` is AngluarJS.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for Spending your time reading all the answer! Can you please Tell me what is the purpose of `AngularJS`?

Comment: @thomas, Just tell me For How may `load` events you want to know the Functionality?

Comment: I can't but they can: https://angularjs.org/.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer for jQuery.  If you're talking about the document loading, there are two main points in time that you can get notified:

1. When the DOM has been parsed and is now safe for manipulation (but some resources in the page may not have yet finished loading like images).
2. When all resources specifically declared in the HTML file have been loaded (like images, but not iframes).  There are multiple ways of registering a notification for each of these two events.

---

For event #2, these two events are triggered at the same time when all resources statically declared in the HTML file (scripts, style sheets, images, etc...) have finished loading (not including iframe content).

```
$(window).load(function()
<body onload="load()">
```

---

These next two are also the same but just different ways of declaring the same event and in modern browsers these are triggered by the `DOMContentLoaded` event which occurs before the above event and is described by MDN as below:

```
$(document).ready()
$(function(){...});
```

DOMContentLoaded is described by MDN:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect
>   a fully-loaded page).

FYI, in older browsers that do not generate the `DOMContentLoaded` event, these functions will be called on a `onreadystatechange` notification when `document.readyState === "complete"` and in a really old browser, it might not be triggered until `window.onload` occurs.

---

If you look into the browser internals, the browser keeps a `document.readyState` variable.  It has possible values of `"loading"`, `"interactive"` and `"complete"`.

`"loading"` was meant to mean that it is in the process of loading the page.

`"interactive"` was meant to mean that the HTML has been parsed, but some sub-resources (other than images) are still loading (perhaps style sheets or scripts)

`"complete"` means that the document has finished loading (except for images and iframes)

So, it would have been possible to expose these other load events in jQuery.  But (and this is the big but), the ONLY state that works consistently across all browsers is the `"complete"` state.  `"interactive"` was probably meant to be the point at which you had a completely parsed DOM and you could start changing the DOM even if things like stylesheets weren't yet loaded, but it turned out to be too bug-ridden in IE for it to be worth even trying to use it as the history of jQuery development shows.

---

jQuery also has another flavor of `.load()` which uses ajax to load new content into a given DOM object which has nothing to do with the initial page loading:

```
$("#content").load("some url", completionFn);
```

This is called by you and immediately fires an ajax function to retrieve whatever content the URL you give it returns.  That content will then be inserted into the DOM element in the jQuery object and when that operation is completed, the `completionFn` will be called.

---

And, `.load()` can also be used to monitor when a specific resource is loaded.  This is primarily used with images:

```
var img = $("<img>");
img.load(function() {
    // called when the image finishes loading
});
img.attr("src", "http://example.com/myimage.jpg");
```

Comment: I feel that this is not all of the load functions which exist between javascript and the two libraries.

Comment: @thomas: You may not feel like it, but that doesn't mean that's not the case ;) If you have a concrete question about a concrete method, we can help you with that. But we can't really do much about a "feeling".

Comment: I don't think that `load(url)` should be mentioned here.

Comment: @FelixKling This answer was expanded considerably between the time of my comment and yours. That said, now that I have your attention, is this a definitive list of (excluding angular) load functions in your opinion?

Comment: @Bergi - the OP is clearly searching for more load events (without being very clear about what exactly they are looking for) so I added it.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have included that. But thank you for taking the time to explain it too. :)

Comment: @jfriend00: Then what about `$.ajax().done` or `$(new Image).load()`? They're load events as well…

Comment: @Bergi - I've already added the image `.load()`.  I wasn't going to go into all the different jQuery functions that can load stuff using Ajax (there are many) except the one called `.load()`.

Comment: Didn't intend to throw ajax into the mix. Just was inquiring about initial page load.