# Ng-include: access child models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-ng-init

I have a template which I want to use in many parts of my application.
The template contains select box with a model assigned.

I include the template by the means of `ng-include`.

```
<span ng-include="'templateWorking'" ng-init="selectModel=data.field"></span>
```

and then in template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateWorking">
   <select ng-model="selectModel">
  <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Of course, it does not work since `ng-include` creates a new child scope.
It is possible to get it work when I use one model (using dot `.` in a model like `data.model`).

But how it is possible in this particular case so I can use this template with different models in different controllers?
Besides, I need to dynamically attach a handler to the `select` (e.g. ng-change="doSmth()").

Thanks in advance.

For the reference:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NiLQyVQGb6X1mA0sVvA1?p=preview

Comment: Typically, if you need reusability, it's best to create a directive. You would have full control of the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it was best to use a directive instead. You can get some control over `ng-include` by using `onload` but if that's not enough, using a directive is your best bet.

Reference: [Difference between onLoad and ng-init in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441775/difference-between-onload-and-ng-init-in-angular)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not related to the issue. The origin of the problem is the fact ng-include creates a new child scope regardless ng-init or onLoad is used. So I wonder how to deal with it. You can see the plunk above to see. I updated it.

Comment: Ok. I understand better what you are after. Let me think a bit. :)

Comment: Maybe this isn't the answer you are looking for but I would just push the template inside a directive. That would give you more control over scoping and probably make it more maintainable as well.

Comment: After some additional digging it seems there is no way to get it work with ng-include so, yes, you're right. Directives seems to be the only possible way to achieve the desired. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I rewrote the answer to reflect that. Thanks. :)