# AngularJS: How to display element by default and toggle it when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to toggle an element that needs to be initially visible. In my case the toggle works fine but the element (`menu` class) is initially hidden...

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ndyn44x6/)

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>
  <div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed">
    <ol>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If not initialized, the default value of `collapsed` is `false`. You can initialize `scope.collapsed = true` in your controller or directive instead of using `ng-init` because [`ng-init` is costly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441775/difference-between-onload-and-ng-init-in-angular).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed">
```

use this line:

```
<div class="menu" ng-show="!collapsed">
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndyn44x6/1/)

Comment: what is deference with OP post?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init="expression" or set in a controller, but I prefer ng-init, since it propagates.