# Difference between ng-init and onload for function invoke [Angular JS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, onload, angularjs-ng-init

I am working on a angular application and have a scenario where i want to focus on a text field on page load. i have tried HTML5 autofocus but have to find an alternative solution for this since there is a browser compatibility issue for the same.

I am planning to invoke a function on page load which will focus on the input field i wanted. I have the following functions with Angular ***ng-init*** and ***onload*** to load the function.

I am not sure which method should i follow in the angular context as i am little confused between their difference.

**onload**

```
    <body onload="focusOnInput()">
       <form name="resetPasswordForm">
          <input name="NewPassword" type="password"/>
       </form>
    </body>
    <script>
       function focusOnInput() {
          document.forms["resetPasswordForm"]["NewPassword"].focus();
       }
    </script>
```

**Angular ng-init**

```
    <body in-init="focusOnInput()">
       <form name="resetPasswordForm">
          <input name="NewPassword" type="password"/>
       </form>
       <script>
          function focusOnInput() {
             document.forms["resetPasswordForm"]["NewPassword"].focus();
          }
       </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between onLoad and ng-init in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441775/difference-between-onload-and-ng-init-in-angular)

Comment: What is the difference between init and load on page life cycle? that is the answer

Answer (score 0):

onload is not in your angular context.  onload function is a callback function on LOAD event of DOM.

your ng-init is in angular context. You need to use angular ng-init.

The ng-init function as shown in your code wont work as is. The function defined in ng-int should be in the angular context. your focusOnInput() isn't in the angular context . It's in javascript context.

if you like to use ng-init you'll need to inject $window into your controller and then use   assign focusOnInput to your $scope and use that method in ng-init

something like this

```
angular.module().controller('TestController',['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window){

 ......

 $scope.myNewFunction = $window.focusOnInput;

 ......



}])
```

and then use this myNewFunction in your ng-init.